# Needs to create a folder with timestamp - 1 hour as its name in linux

Tags: linux, shell, datetime

I'm trying to create a folder with the following conditions:

1. needs to create a folder with timestamp as its name, e.g.: `abc_20230613_17:30:00`
2. If you are creating the directory at 18:30:00 hrs on your local machine, then the name of the directory we should be creating will be like `abc_20230613_17:30:00`".

I'm able to create a directory with the current timestamp by using the following command:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/local_dir/abc_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
```

but I need to create a folder as `abc_(current_timstamp - 1 hour)`

Comment: Get current time in seconds, substract 3600, convert seconds to required format.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is written in bash.

```bash
# Step 1: Get unix timestamp.
timestamp="$(date +%s)"

# Step 2: Subtract 1 hour from the timestamp.
timestamp="$((timestamp - 3600))"

# Step 3: Convert timestamp to your desired format.
date -d @"${timestamp}"
```

Everything in *one* statement:

```bash
mkdir -p "/path/to/local_dir/abc_$(date -d @$(($(date +%s) - 3600)) +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) I'll assume GNU date

```
date '+%T'                  # 12:33:58
date -d '1 hour ago' '+%T'  # 11:33:58
```

For `-d`, see [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html)